# Use CNN for time series regression | How to implement sliding window?

Tags: python, keras, time-series

I'm trying to use CNN for time series regression in python. I have 9 elements in each time step (from sensor readings) and the output (target/reference) is 4 elements.

```
Input Shape = (time steps, 9)
Output Shape = (time steps, 4)
```

Based on papers I should use rolling windows, such as:
[image]

I don't understand how could I implement that. Should I convert the input to as follows?

```
Input Shape = (Time Steps, Sliding Windows Length, 9)
```

The Model is:

```
    ####################################################################################################################
    # Define ANN Model
    # define two sets of inputs
    acc   =  layers.Input(shape=(3,1,))
    gyro  =  layers.Input(shape=(3,1,))
    
    # the first branch operates on the first input
    x = Conv1D(256, 1, activation='relu')(acc)
    x = Conv1D(128, 1, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Conv1D(64, 1, activation='relu')(x)
    x = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3)(x)
    x = Model(inputs=acc, outputs=x)
    
    # the second branch opreates on the second input
    y = Conv1D(256, 1, activation='relu')(gyro)
    y = Conv1D(128, 1, activation='relu')(y)
    y = Conv1D(64, 1, activation='relu')(y)
    y = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3)(y)
    y = Model(inputs=gyro, outputs=y)
    
    
    # combine the output of the three branches
    combined =  layers.concatenate([x.output,  y.output])
    
    # combined outputs
    z = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, dropout=0.25, return_sequences=False,activation='tanh'))(combined)
    z = Reshape((256,1),input_shape=(128,))
    z = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, dropout=0.25, return_sequences=False,activation='tanh'))(combined)
    
    #z = Dense(10, activation="relu")(z)
    z = Flatten()(z)
    z = Dense(4, activation="linear")(z)
    model = Model(inputs=[x.input, y.input], outputs=z)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01),metrics=['accuracy','mse'],run_eagerly=True) #, callbacks=[tensorboard]
    
    model.summary()


    Model: "model_2"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)           [(None, 3, 1)]       0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_2 (InputLayer)           [(None, 3, 1)]       0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 conv1d (Conv1D)                (None, 3, 256)       512         ['input_1[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 conv1d_3 (Conv1D)              (None, 3, 256)       512         ['input_2[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 conv1d_1 (Conv1D)              (None, 3, 128)       32896       ['conv1d[0][0]']                 
                                                                                                  
 conv1d_4 (Conv1D)              (None, 3, 128)       32896       ['conv1d_3[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 conv1d_2 (Conv1D)              (None, 3, 64)        8256        ['conv1d_1[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 conv1d_5 (Conv1D)              (None, 3, 64)        8256        ['conv1d_4[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling1d (MaxPooling1D)   (None, 1, 64)        0           ['conv1d_2[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1D)  (None, 1, 64)       0           ['conv1d_5[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 concatenate (Concatenate)      (None, 1, 128)       0           ['max_pooling1d[0][0]',          
                                                                  'max_pooling1d_1[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 bidirectional_1 (Bidirectional  (None, 256)         263168      ['concatenate[0][0]']            
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 flatten (Flatten)              (None, 256)          0           ['bidirectional_1[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 dense (Dense)                  (None, 4)            1028        ['flatten[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 347,524
Trainable params: 347,524
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: I have same conceptual trouble

Comment: @fede72bari I shared my written code as an answer to this post. Please do not hesitate to contact  if you have any questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this code to solve this problem. This code requires windows size and stride value.

```
def load_dataset(gyro_data, acc_data, ori_data, window_size, stride):
    x_gyro = []
    x_acc = []
    x_ori = []
    for idx in range(0, gyro_data.shape[0] - window_size - 1, stride):
        x_gyro.append(gyro_data[idx + 1: idx + 1 + window_size, :])
        x_acc.append(acc_data[idx + 1: idx + 1 + window_size, :])
        x_ori.append(mag_data[idx + 1: idx + 1 + window_size, :])

    x_gyro = np.reshape(
        x_gyro, (len(x_gyro), x_gyro[0].shape[0], x_gyro[0].shape[1]))
    x_acc = np.reshape(
        x_acc, (len(x_acc), x_acc[0].shape[0], x_acc[0].shape[1]))
    x_ori = np.reshape(x_ori, (len(x_ori), x_ori[0].shape[0]))
    return [x_gyro, x_acc], [x_ori]
```